# Devise force logout for some users from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Is it possible to force logout for SOME of the users through Devise.

In my setup, I am using rails 4.1.15 with Devise 1.5.4. Sessions are persisted in db and there is no direct mapping with user ids. Is there a Devise way to logout against some of the users NOT ALL.

I tried resetting password as a proxy which logs out immediately but not always.

```
user_obj.update_attributes(:password => "some_random_string")
```

Comment: Do you need to do it in the controller or rails console?

Comment: In controller, for example an admin will be able to remove/nullify session for a list of users not himself ? And there are millions of records in session db cant iterate just to remove session for 10 users.

Answer (score 4):

I can propose you next solution.

Add a new column for `admin` that called `force_logout:boolean`

In any your controller add a new action to set `force_logout` to `true`. Ex.:

```
# in admins_controller.rb

def force_logout
  admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  admin.update_column(:force_logout, true)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

In `application_controller.rb` add `before_action` to logout user if `force_logout` is `true`

```
before_action :check_force_logout

def check_force_logout
  if current_user && current_user.force_logout?
    current_user.update_column(:force_logout, false)
    sign_out(current_user)
  end
end
```

Too you need reset `force_logout` column after admin will be signed in. Usually you can do it `session_controller.rb` in action `create`.

Comment: The above solution wont log out immediately, it will when the user tries to login next time which I dont want. I just want to delete their current active sessions not the one when the user tries to login next time. I dont want to remove the session which is created after setting the force logout field to true.

Comment: No, `check_force_logout`  is called for every request and will logout immediatelly. Probably need to add redirect after sign_out()

Comment: Yes as I mentioned above it will work. But I want to destroy the active sessions. Your above solution will fail even when a genuine login tries to open from a different browser with a brand new session as the flag is still set to true. I dont want to wait for the next request to arrive. I want to do it at admin level.

Comment: When use websoskets to notify client app/browser to remove session's cookie and reload page.

Answer (score 1):

Time to exhume this one. The only way I was able to solve this issue was by accessing the sessions. It is slow but it works.

```
  def sign_out_different_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    sessions = ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.where("updated_at > ?", Time.now - 480.minutes).all
    sessions.each do |s|
      if s.data['user_email'] == @user.email
        s.delete and return
      end
    end
  end
```

I needed to change the session expiration on the user object for my purposes, so I added this into the method, as well. YMMV

```
 @user.session_expires_at = Time.now
 @user.save
```